# http bcrypt sending username and password

Tags: http, post, encryption, bcrypt

Is it safe to send a bcrypt encrypted username and password through a http post?  I basically just want to set a server up for my friends with a username and password that is encrypted so they can access stuff on my server.

Comment: Password and username should be sent in plain text to server and there checked through bcrypt

Comment: To add to Didar_Uranov's comment, you can use SSL/TLS to encrypt traffic over the wire. With this approach you don't have to implement client-side encryption. But realize that this security hinges on trusting the SSL/TLS implementations, certificate authorities, and certificate maintainers.

Comment: Password hashing algorithms like bcrypt solve a different problem. If you store a cryptographic hash (e.g. bcrypt) of the user's password instead of the password itself, it's much more challenging for attackers who gain access to the password database to discover the actual user passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It's just about as dangerous as doing all communication in plaintext without the safety net of SSL/TLS. There's not much benefit.

If you care about security, make sure all usernames and passwords are encrypted over the wire by using a common standard like SSL/TLS. There have been a number of vulnerabilities in this approach lately (e.g. OpenSSL), so it's worth investigating ways to establish secure communication channels. [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) is a great resource for web application security strategies.

Bcrypt isn't for encrypting communications, but it is a cryptographic hash function that's particularly good for password hashing.

What does the server need to know when deciding whether to accept or reject a login attempt? It has to decide whether the username and password provided by the client are correct. Interestingly, you can do that by storing a derivative of the password that difficult to reverse rather than the password itself. The benefit? If somebody gains access to your password database, your user's passwords should still be secure. That's not to say you should publish your password database, but it's better to engineer everything as though that could happen.